# Retrieving values dynamically using db4o in android

Tags: android, database

In my app I have created two edit text for name and address and a save button,I want to store these values  when the user clicks on the save button but using `db4o` and also retrieve the edit text values but its not working.Your valuable answer(code) will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please post the code also..

Comment: I have referred this link but it doesn't work.http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-db4o-android-application